# C program to replace series of blanks by single blanks not working…

Tags: c

**Exercise 1-9** in *The C Programming Language* by Denis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan, second edition:

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

Given that I'm using the book as a reference, I know only the C principles which have been discussed in the book up to **Exercise 1-9**, that is, variable assignments, while- and for-loops, if-statements, symbolic constants, character I/O via `getchar()` and `putchar()`, escape sequences and the `printf()` function. Maybe I'm forgetting something, but that's most of it. (I'm at page 20, where the exercise is at.)

Here's my (not working) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { // As long as EOF is not met, repeat the following…
        if(c == ' ') { // If the input character is a blank, proceed (otherwise skip)…
            putchar(c); // Output the blank space which was just inputed…
            while(c == ' ') { // As long as more spaces keep coming in, don't do anything (proceed when another character comes along)…
                ;
            }
        }
        else { // When a character other than a blank is inputed, output that character…
            putchar(c);
        } // Now retest the master while-loop condition (EOF not met) and proceed…
    }
}
```

What I'm getting as a result is a working input-to-output program, that keeps on inputting and stops outputting the moment a blank is typed. (An exception to this is if the blank is removed with a backspace before entering a new line in the console.)

For example, the input `abcde\nabcde abcde\nabcde` will yield the output `abcde`, omitting the second and third lines, given that a blank is contained in the former. Here I am obviously using `\n` to represent an inputted new line (normally using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key).

What have I done wrong, and what could I do to fix this issue? I know there are several working models of this program spread all over the internet, but I'm wondering why this one (which is my creation) in particular doesn't work. Again, do note that my knowledge of C is mostly limited to the first twenty pages of the book whose details are provided below.

### Specs:

I'm running Eclipse version 2021-12 (4.22.0) on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I downloaded the pre-compiled Eclipse version from the official *Eclipse.org* website.

### References:

1. Kernighan, B.W. and Ritchie, D.M. (1988). *The C programming language / ANSI C Version*. Englewood Cliffs, N.J.: Prentice Hall.
   ‌

Comment: What do you think the three lines `while(c == ' ') {`, `;` and `}` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while(c == ' ')` is forever loop.
you should try to remember previous character and if prevous character is whitespace and current character is also whitespace, skip it.